# How do I implement a method to get and return the LifeCycle

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, lifecycle, page-lifecycle, android-viewpager2

I have issue with the `FragmentStateAdapter` asking for LifeCycle, kindly help how I can set and pass the LifeCycle in the line of code below.

```
viewPager2.adapter = myViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, getCurrentLifeCycle())
```

Here is the `myViewPagerAdapter` method

```
private fun myViewPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager, lifeCycle: Lifecycle): RecyclerView.Adapter<*> {
    //val items = items // avoids resolving the ViewModel multiple times

    return object : FragmentStateAdapter(fm, lifeCycle) {
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            // Show fragments.size total pages.
            return fragments.size
        }

        private val fragments = arrayOf(
            MyPostsFragment(),
            RecentPostsFragment()
        )

        override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
            return fragments[position]
        }

    }
}
```

After some digging, I got this, LifeCycle is `@NonNull`

```
public FragmentStateAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager,
        @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle) {
    mFragmentManager = fragmentManager;
    mLifecycle = lifecycle;
    super.setHasStableIds(true);
}
```

Help me complete this method to return the current LifeCycle

```
private fun getCurrentLifeCycle(): LifeCycle { return ??? }
```

Comment: Did you try calling `getLifecycle()`? Refer : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleOwner.html#getLifecycle()

Comment: damn it works im so dumb , although I had tried it!... Thank you.

Comment: great! posted an answer with the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call `getLifecycle()` which returns a `LifeCycle` object.

See more : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleOwner.html#getLifecycle()